# /storage/emulated/0 is missing. Apps can't find the directory

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 6.0-marshmallow, storage, mount

It began when I accidentally formatted the internal storage with TWRP.

Now the OS can't mount the internal storage and the `/storge/emulated/0` directory is missing but when I go to settings -> storage and usb I can see that the internal storage is still there.

I can access my files through `/data/media` but the apps can't find the directory which is missing from `/storage`.

I flashed my stock kitkat ROM and it is able to detect and mount it (mounted at `/storage/sdcard0`) apps can access it as well

What can I do, I flashed multiple ROMs (both cyanogen and AOSP based but they can't find it!)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that it is now located at `/storage/sdcard0`  since you flashed different ROMs with different configurations as you suggested,

alternately to run the following in emulator ;

```
mount -w -o remount rootfs /
```

then ;

```
ln -s /data/media/0 /sdcard
```

You can check with ;

```
ls -l -a /sdcard
```

Credits:

1. [/storage/emulated/0 missing](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2320006)
2. [Android 4.3 breaks Lil Debi. sdcard: '/storage/emulated/0' not a directory](https://github.com/guardianproject/lildebi/issues/66)